Showing continuity of a function defined on $\mathbb{R^3}$
Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{R^3}, d)$, where the distance function is given for $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3), y=(y_1,y_2,y_3) \in \mathbb{R^3}$ as:
$d: \mathbb{R^3} \times \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$
$(x,y) \mapsto \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2-y_2)^2 + (x_3-y_3)^2}$.
For the matrix $A \in Mat_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ define the function $f$ on the metric space as $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}, x \mapsto Ax$. How can it be shown that the function $f$ is continuous? I'm aware of the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, but I don't know how to apply it with this distance function.
This example appeared in my introductory analyis course. The chapter on continuity up until this point only covered the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity of a function over the complex numbers, then the equivalence of that to the sequential definition, then the generalization of that definition to a metric space. No other theorems have been covered. So I'm wondering if/how this example can be solved using only that knowledge.

At the end of $\epsilon$-$\delta$, you look at $d(A(x+\delta), Ax)$.  Are you able to expand that (to convince yourself that what @BrevanEllefsen is saying applies to your problem)?

@duratsch You need to be more explicit about what you know and what you don't about multivariate maps. Do you know that a multivariate map is continuous if its coordinate maps are continuous? Do you know that all norms are equivalent in finite-dimensional spaces... Without those precisions, it is impossible to provide an answer adapted to your current level in math. Please update your question.

Denote
\begin{equation*}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and then for any $u=( u_{1} ,u_{2} ,u_{3})^{\top } \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, we have
\begin{equation*}
f( u) =\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}\\
u_{2}\\
u_{3}
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} u_{1} +a_{12} u_{2} +a_{13} u_{3}\\
a_{21} u_{1} +a_{22} u_{2} +a_{23} u_{3}\\
a_{31} u_{1} +a_{32} u_{2} +a_{33} u_{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
thus
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
 & |f( u) |^{2}\\
= & \sum _{k=1}^{3}( a_{k1} u_{1} +a_{k2} u_{2} +a_{k3} u_{3})^{2}\\
\leqslant  & \sum _{k=1}^{3}\left( a_{k1}^{2} +a_{k2}^{2} +a_{k3}^{2}\right)\left( u_{1}^{2} +u_{2}^{2} +u_{3}^{2}\right)\\
= & |A|^{2} |u|^{2} ,\quad \text{where} \ |A|=\sqrt{\sum _{k=1}^{3} a_{k\ell }^{2}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
therefore, for an arbitrary, therefore, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, any $\varepsilon  >0$, selecting $\delta =\varepsilon /|A|$, then whenever $x'\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ satisfies $|x-x'|\leqslant \delta $, we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
 & |f( x) -f( x') |^{2}\\
= & |Ax-Ax'|^{2} =|A( x-x') |^{2}\\
= & |f( x-x') |^{2}\\
\leqslant  & |A|^{2} |x-x'|^{2}\\
= & |A|^{2}\frac{\varepsilon ^{2}}{|A|^{2}} =\varepsilon ^{2} .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
thus $|f( x) -f( x') |< \varepsilon $. This shows that $f( x)$ is continuous.
The only extra issue is that $A$ might be all zero so $|A|=0$, and dividing it does not make sense. For this case, $\delta $ can actually be anything you like, since $f( x) -f( x')$ is always zero.
